# Built-in storage not detected

Tags: internal-storage

well I just bought a lenovo s920, at the first time I'm doing a system update and it works fine, then I'm doing another system update S920_ROW_S114_130626_TO_S920_ROW_S117_130815 (79.83MB), I dont know if it's failed or what, after that my built-in storage not detected. I keep getting notification "Damaged Built-in storage" that asking me to format and even I'm doing it, it cant be format.

My Storage setting become like this:

```
INTERNAL STORAGE
Total Space: 3.62GB
Available: 379MB

BUILT-IN STORAGE (no information)
```

then when I check spaces with app Freespace:

```
Cache /cache:         Total space->   123.08MB
Internal /data:       total space-> 1,008.29MB
Preload /preload:     total space->   197.01MB
Protect_s /protect_s: total space->     8.89MB
System /system:       total space->   788.39MB
                                    2,125.66MB
```

so there's missing around 1,400MB.
I guess this is built-in storage, how can I recover it? and create it again as built-in storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a hardware problem, nothing I could do about it.

I took it to a service center and got the hardware replaced.

Answer (score 0):

HMM the only thing I can think of would be to get clockwork or something similar and format the space and reflash the rom.